# Read local/static file in Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

My project is created in **Blazor WASM** ( I do not want to use Blazor server )

I would like to read XSD files from wwwroot:

[image]

Inside my XsdService.cs - c# class I was trying:

```
string pathToXsd = Path.Combine("plcda","extPL_r2.xsd");
string transformataHTML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToXsd);
```

However, I always get errors:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find a part of the path "/plcda/extPL_r2.xsd".
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/plcda/extPL_r2.xsd".
```

So is there any chance to include custom/static/local files to Blazor WASM? And read them even if app is offline?

Comment: You need to reference them in the manifest and access them as remote files.

Comment: Cool, could you add some sample code or links?

Comment: See http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a Http GET call to the files. Think of Blazor wasm as a SPA application. All of the files that are required to **run** your app are downloaded into a users browser. Everything else like images are fetched on request. Like an images is requested by the browser.

```
@inject HttpClient _client

@code {
    async Task GetXDSFile()
    {
        var byteOfTheFile = await _client.GetByteArrayAsync("plcda/extPL_r2.xsd");
    }
}
```

This sample just fetches the file as byte array. Other version of the Get maybe more sutaible for you like `GetStreamAsync`.

Comment: Ok, yet is the method gonna work when the app has no internet? The app is installed by PWA

Comment: Upvoted, I can load now files. :) However, I am still curious if the method works when no internet.

Comment: For this to work, some webserver is required. Reading a file using httpclient and file:/// scheme is not permitted by Blazor.

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski, how exactly do you envision loading a file over the Internet if there is no Internet?

Comment: Just read the answer. Embedded files are already downloaded / included in the build bundle. The file is treated like a resource, that is locally available. Like an image, once it is downloaded the browser does not load the image from wire, instead the browser will use the local copy. Also called cached resource. (That how a browsers works)

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core 6 you can add provider mappings to your client project's program.cs to serve static files.

For example I need to load a 3d model (.obj, .mtl files):

**Blazor WASM Client Only Project**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;


var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".obj", "application/obj");
provider.Mappings.Add(".mtl", "application/mtl");

builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ContentTypeProvider = provider;
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

If you have an asp.net core hosted project you can simply put this in the server project's program.cs file instead and you shouldn't need to add nuget package references.

**Blazor WASM Asp.net Core Hosted Project**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;


var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".babylon", "application/javascript");
provider.Mappings.Add(".obj", "application/obj");
provider.Mappings.Add(".mtl", "application/mtl");
builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ContentTypeProvider = provider;
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: How would this files be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

"Local/static" file in the context of Blazor WebAssembly is a bit misleading. The application executes fully in the user's browser.

If you have some files that you want to have available, you can add them to the application manifest, so that they get downloaded in the background and cached in the browser. Then, any network request to that file from the application will be served from the browser cache.
There are other options, too. You could download any files from the application and cache them manually in an IndexedDb or OPFS. The next time you need them, load them from the cache manually if there is no network.
Hope this helps.